# Difference between Canon cameras and lens?

Tags: canon

Is there a big difference in photos taken with the Canon 100mm macro lens, with the 100D body vs. the 7D? I have a Canon 100D and it looks like photos taken with the 100D are terrible, nothing nice and beautiful!

Comment: what do you mean with 'terrible'? Can you post some example of terrible photo with your 100d+100macro and other one better?

Comment: Assuming that you're comparing photos that you've taken with the 100D versus photos others have taken with the 7D, the big difference is in the photographer, not the camera.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a quick search of Flickr using [Pixel Peeper](http://www.pixel-peeper.com/adv/?lens=11&camera=1799&perpage=12&focal_min=none&focal_max=none&aperture_min=none&aperture_max=none&iso_min=none&iso_max=none&exp_min=none&exp_max=none&res=3) returns the following results for

100D with 100mm f/2.8 Macro - http://www.flickr.com/photos/21046994@N08/9256855808

7D with 100mm f/2.8 Macro - http://www.flickr.com/photos/32339529@N04/5351386823

Both cameras are able to take fine photos using the Macro lens.  The problem exists between camera and ground.  Try working with better lighting and a good tripod.  This should help your macro photos come out much better.  You may also have to use a smaller aperture to get a deep enough depth of field for the kind of shots you want, which may require longer exposures, depending on what you are shooting.

Comment: `The problem exists between camera and ground.` Could you please clarify what this means?

Comment: @BartArondson Sounds similar to 'the most important equipment in photography is 6 inches behind the lens.' Great pictures have been taken with the worst equipment (see DigitalRev's cheap camera, pro photographer challenge on YouTube) and terrible pictures have been taken with the best equipment. Knowledge is key and there is no substitute, no matter what the sales rep says.

Comment: @BartArondson - I left it intentionally vague and is a reference to PEBCAK errors in computer (problem exists between chair and keyboard).  It could refer to either the photographer lacking the necessary skill/training or not having sufficient stable support for the camera.  Either (or both) could be a problem.  Without a photo to analyse, can't really be more specific.

Comment: I've also heard PEBCAK errors referenced as ID 10-T errors. Truck mechanics will sometimes say the problem is a loose nut between the steering wheel and the driver's seat.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Yes, ID10T is the far more critical form of PEBCAK errors and is resistant to fixing due to the inability to follow basic instructions.